# How to properly access and change other views

Tags: java, android, view, wear-os, onlongclicklistener

I'm trying to build a function where if a page is longclicked, the color scheme will change to black and white on every page in the app. If the page, or a different page, is long clicked, the changes should revert. Here's a sample of what I have. If you want to see more specific pieces of code, let me know.

```
View sigView;
View rootView;
View tunerView;
public boolean pm;
public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    sigView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_sig, container,false);
    rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_metronome,container);
    tunerView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tuner,container);

    final TextView tvTempo=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.metro_disp);
    final TextView NumView = (TextView) sigView.findViewById(R.id.Sig_Num);
    final TextView tv_note=(TextView) tunerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_note);        
    final ImageView time_sig_bar= ImageView)sigView.findViewById(R.id.time_sig_bar);

    //**Lots more lines just like above for other elements

time_sig_bar.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (!pm) {
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                //**Code to run

                pm=true;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm",pm).apply();
            } else{
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //**More code to run

                pm=false;
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("pm",pm).apply();
            }
//**code is copied for other elements to respond to longclick
```

I copied and pasted this code to the other pages (with a couple small changes). On one of the other pages, the elements on that page change, but it won't change elements on other pages. Also, I don't know how to set it up so that the color will change back from another page. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe have a new class that holds state data for your views.  True if longclicked, false otherwise. Then you could set the state on longlick to whatever the state isn't currently